# can't make the db work on localhost with flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am using now the most basic code and it is still not working:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

mysql = MySQL()
app = Flask(__name__)

# MySQL configurations
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'people'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    conn = mysql.connect()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT * from tbl_user"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    return results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I have tried to connect on localhost to my db via Mysql cli and it works fine. I have used mysql -u root to enter and it accepts it then I use use people and it works fine then I can do select statements.

Here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1478, in full_dispatch_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1577, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers.py", line 847, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers.py", line 57, in _run_wsgi_app
    return _run_wsgi_app(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\test.py", line 871, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

But as you can see, as soon as I use Flask, I get this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with flaskext.mysql and db connection. Inside `@app.route('/test')` statement you return a tuple which is a result of a select from database.
In Flask you should return something [appropriate](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#about-responses).

Answer (score 1):

Your view should return a template or HTML code (in string format). I guess your trying to show the results of your database query, so a proper way to do that is using the `render_template()` function to pass the data through the template.
Take a look here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#rendering-templates